# How send the byteArray from Native C to my Android app

Tags: android

I am developing a Native application name test.c  and I want to return the arrayofByte from the native C file ,I able to compile and the .so file is generate when i run my Application

```
    05-08 13:04:08.477: D/dalvikvm(945): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.ssg.nativelibtest/lib/libnativelibtest.so 0x45f3da78, skipping init
```

getting this message with out any crash in my application so how to resolve the calling of Nativefile.
for the reference I am giveing my test.c file
this is file written in C I am calling the .so file Java appliaction

```
jbyteArray Java_com_ssg_nativelibtest_MainActivity_getEncryptionKey(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{

    unsigned char ukey[] = { 'H','A','R','D','C','O','D','E','D',' ','K','E','Y','1','2','3'};
    int lengthOfArray = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, ukey);
    //jsize lengthOfArray =(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, ukey);
    jbyteArray byteKey = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, lengthOfArray);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, byteKey, 0, lengthOfArray, (jbyte *)ukey);
    return byteKey;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and code into a more readable format the next time. It will definitely increase the number of responses to your question.

Comment: ok sure will do that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries):

> The JNI_OnLoad function should look something like this if written in
>   C++:

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Get jclass with env->FindClass.
    // Register methods with env->RegisterNatives.

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Comment: Stephen I have writeen in my java file System.load Library("nativelibtest"); actually what happened my C file is compile successfully but in my Java file when I call the native method its i blank (the screen display with no value  for fraction of sec and it goes to background) how to reslove